# Value Error: Microsecond must be in 0..999999

Tags: python, win32com

Hi i am using the library win32com.client to read emails from an outlook sharedmailbox and i get a value error:Microsecond must be in 0..999999. I tried formatting the "ReceivedDate" as "%Y-%D-%M %H:%M:%S" with no luck. do you know what else i can try?

Question 2: im trying to count how many emails have not been replied to but i dont see a property for that in the documentation. SO i went with reading all that have a "FlagRequest" marked as completed. I would have the representatives go with this process as a way to tell if the emails have been complete.

```
import win32com.client

def readEmail():
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item('SharedMailbox, TEST')
inbox = folder.Folders.Item('Inbox')
messages = inbox.Items

counter = 0
for message in messages:
    rcvd_dt = message.ReceivedTime
    if message.FlagRequest != 'Follow up' and str(rcvd_dt) >= '2020-06-01 00:00:00':
    counter  +=1
    print(counter)
    print(received_dt)
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/TEST/PycharmProjects/TEST/Metrics.py", line 422, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Users/TEST/PycharmProjects/TEST/Metrics.py", line 409, in main
readEmail()
File "C:/Users/TEST/PycharmProjects/TEST/Metrics.py", line 89, in readEmail
rcvd_dt = message.ReceivedTime
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999
```

What i tried:

```
rcvd_dt= datetime.strptime(str(rcvd_dt.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but get error:

```
valueerror: time data '2' does not match format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

if i try:

```
rcvd_dt= datetime.strptime(str(rcvd_dt.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

i get :

```
valueerror: time data '2020-06-16 08:53:56' does not match format %Y-%m-%d.%f'
```

Comment: (1) please show the code you were using which gives you the error related to microseconds, and please show the complete traceback of the error message (see [mre]). (2) Question 2 seems unrelated. Please ask only one question per post. If you have two separate problems, please create two separate questions.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have edited my post.

Comment: I think this is related to this bug
https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/issues/75

Comment: @Mr.J hank you, i checked it out. I tried to remove microseconds but still get errors which i have added to my post